# Exporting functions from a simple library which imports from other libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, node-modules, sentry

I have a simple repository "logger" with an index.js file with the following content:

```
exports.log = function (message) {
  console.log('LOG: ' + message)
}
```

It works as expected when I publish the repository, and add it as a dependency in a node.js repository like:

```
import { log } from '@mystuff/logger'

export async function logIt(){
 log('Stuff')
}
```

But when I try to update the logger repository with a dependency on another repo Sentry, as below, I get an error message:

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/node"

exports.log = function (message) {
  console.log('LOG: ' + message)
}

exports.notify = function () {
  Sentry.captureMessage(`notify?`)
}
```

Error message:

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/node"
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I've tried adding `"type": "module"` to my logger package.json, but that seems to require dynamic imports which I do not want to use.

How do I include Sentry in my logger repo?

Comment: You can import only native nodejs modules or imported packages.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I am not sure what that means though - can you please elaborate on how I can achieve what I want, maybe with an example? So I guess Sentry is not a native nodejs module, but you say I can import "imported packages". Can I make Sentry an imported package?

Comment: Sorry, typo there. What I meant was you can import only installed packages (from package registry like npm).

Comment: `@mystuff/logger` I could not find this package in npm registry.

Comment: It is a private repo, but the code is shown above.

Comment: You can check if there is `@mystuff` folder in `node_modules`. If it is not there, then the module is not installed and you may try re-installing it.